# Python Multiprocessing - Start N threads and run new thread after one completes till timeout and capture results

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am basically trying create a script to do load testing where I have to keep running N number of queries in parallel and as soon as one thread finishes, I want to kickoff next thread and so on until the timeout seconds are reached. This way at all times N threads are running in parallel. I want to keep it running till the timeout threshold is reached.

I found the ThreadPool to be somewhat close to accomplishing it but I could not figure out how can I add timeout for the main thread and capture all the required information for each child thread before exiting when parent is timed out or killed:

```py
def query_data(q):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    id = q[0]  # Runs the main logic
    time.sleep(5)
    end_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    run_time = float((end_time - start_time).total_seconds())
    # Captures more details regarding the thread...
    # Add a way to capture results even when the parent timeout is reached
    # so the running/killed threads details can be also captured.
    return {"id": id, "run_time": run_time}


def run_processes(queries, max_threads=5):
    # Add timeout for the parent thread and kill parent thread
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=max_threads)
    threads = []
    while queries:
        q = queries.pop()
        threads.append(pool.apply_async(query_data, (q,)))
    result = []
    for t in threads:
        result.append(t.get())
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
    return result
```

Comment: If you want to always have N threads running, then why don't you simply start N threads, and have each thread _continually_ run one query after another for the entire duration of the test? What benefit do you expect to gain by destroying a thread and creating a new thread for each query? Why not re-use the threads?

Comment: P.S., If there really is some reason to create a new thread for each query, one simple way to do that would be to have each query thread create its own successor as the last thing it does before it dies.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) which allows you to cancel work if it hasn't started yet when you call `shutdown`

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time
import datetime

def query_data(q):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    id = q  # Runs the main logic
    time.sleep(5)
    end_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    run_time = float((end_time - start_time).total_seconds())
    # Captures more details regarding the thread...
    # Add a way to capture results even when the parent timeout is reached
    # so the running/killed threads details can be also captured.
    return {"id": id, "run_time": run_time}



def run_processes(queries, max_threads=5, timeout = 0.1):
    start_time = time.time()

    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_threads)
    threads = []
    while queries:
        q = queries.pop()
        threads.append((q,pool.submit(query_data, q)))

    time_to_wait = timeout - (time.time() - start_time)
    time.sleep(time_to_wait)

    pool.shutdown(cancel_futures=True)

    result = []
    for t in threads:
        if not t[1].cancelled():
            result.append(t[1].result())
        else:
            result.append((t[0],"Failed"))
    return result

res = run_processes(list(range(10)),max_threads=5,timeout=3)
for item in res:
    print(item)
```

```
{'id': 9, 'run_time': 5.001778}
{'id': 8, 'run_time': 5.001778}
{'id': 7, 'run_time': 5.001778}
{'id': 6, 'run_time': 5.000781}
{'id': 5, 'run_time': 5.000781}
(4, 'Failed')
(3, 'Failed')
(2, 'Failed')
(1, 'Failed')
(0, 'Failed')
```

if the main thread is killed then the children will also be killed so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, I tried running it but for some reason the child threads are running until it's completed regardless of the pool.shutdown. Also I need to capture the end status of the child thread if it's terminated. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Incognito , only work that hasn't started yet can be stopped, i have updated the example above to show what that means, if the timeout is after 3 seconds then only 5 jobs are done, because each job needs 5 seconds to be done, so in 3 seconds the first 5 jobs would start, but later jobs won't, as for capturing the end status ... you can add an `else` to the cancelled check and put a failure instead, otherwise you could also return something to signal failure from that function, that's outside the scope of question and depends on the actual implementation of your functions.

Comment: Can you please let me know which python version are you using because I tried on multiple envs but getting error on python 3.7+ version - TypeError: shutdown() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cancel_futures'. I want to run this on 3.8 env

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. Anyone using less than 3.9 python version, use code snippet mentioned in below thread rather than shutdown: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65443612/gracefully-exit-using-threadpoolexecutor